# Finding the number of minimizers of a sextic polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials, contest-math, maxima-minima

From the Indian [Joint Entrance Examination – Main](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Entrance_Examination_%E2%80%93_Main):

> Find the number of minimizers of the following sextic univariate polynomial $$f(x) = 10x^6 - 24x^5 + 15x^4 - 40x^2 + 108$$

---

I know the general method for cubic polynomials is finding roots of $f'(x)$ and checking for sign of $f''(x)$ at those points, but I am not able to solve for degree $6$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo jee mains

Comment: @Anusha You don't have to "*solve*" $\,f'(x)\,$, you only need to find the number of real roots.

Comment: And from which year?

Comment: @dxiv can you elaborate

Comment: @Anusha You need to find how many real roots $\,f'(x)=20 x \left(3 \left(x^2 - x\right)^2 - 4\right)\,$ has.

Comment: What exactly is a minimizer? The minimum?

Comment: If it is the local minimas, then the method you are describing works for any (twice differentiable) function, not just cubic polynomials.

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x) = 10x^6 - 24x^5 + 15x^4 - 40x^2 + 108$$

We have
$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=60 x^5 - 120 x^4 + 60 x^3 - 80 x
\\\\&=20x(3x^4 - 6 x^3 + 3 x^2 - 4)
\\\\&=20x\bigg(3x^2(x^2-2x+1)-4\bigg)
\\\\&=20x\bigg((\sqrt 3x(x-1))^2-2^2\bigg)
\\\\&=20x\bigg(\sqrt 3x(x-1)-2\bigg)\bigg(\sqrt 3x(x-1)+2\bigg)
\\\\&=20x\underbrace{(\sqrt 3x^2-\sqrt 3x-2)}_{g(x)}\underbrace{(\sqrt 3x^2-\sqrt 3x+2)}_{\text{positive}}\end{align}$$

So, $$f'(x)=0\iff x=0,\alpha,\beta$$
where $\alpha=\frac{\sqrt 3-\sqrt{3+8\sqrt 3}}{2\sqrt 3},\beta=\frac{\sqrt 3+\sqrt{3+8\sqrt 3}}{2\sqrt 3}$.

We have
$$f''(x)=20\underbrace{(15x^4 - 24x^3 + 9x^2 -4)}_{h(x)}$$

Dividing $h(x)$ by $g(x)$ gives

$$h(x) = (5\sqrt 3 x^2 - 3\sqrt 3x + 10)g(x) + 4\sqrt 3 x + 16$$

So, we finally have
$$f''(0)=-80\lt 0$$
and
$$\begin{align}f''(\alpha)&=20h(\alpha)
\\\\&=20(4\sqrt 3\alpha+16)
\\\\&=20\bigg(4\sqrt 3\times\frac{\sqrt 3-\sqrt{3+8\sqrt 3}}{2\sqrt 3}+16\bigg)
\\\\&=20\bigg(2\sqrt 3-2\sqrt{3+8\sqrt 3}+16\bigg)
\\\\&=40\bigg(8-\sqrt{3+8\sqrt 3}+\sqrt 3\bigg)
\\\\&\gt 40\bigg(8-\sqrt{9+8\times 2}+\sqrt 3\bigg)
\\\\&=40(8-5+\sqrt 3)
\\\\&\gt 0\end{align}$$
and
$$f''(\beta)=20h(\beta)=20(4\sqrt 3\beta+16)\gt 0$$

Therefore, we can say that $\alpha,\beta$ are the only minimizers, so the number of the minimizers is $\color{red}2$.

Answer (score 1):

First $f'(x)=20x(3x^4-6x^3+3x^2-4)$ and $f''(x)=20(15x^4-24x^3+9x^2-4)$ and $f'''(x)=120x(10x^2-12x+3)$

Now my goal is to find out locations of the roots of these three polynomials by trying out small values for $x$ and using the intermediate value theorem.

**Roots of the third derivative:**

We notice that $f'''(x)$ has a root at $0$ and also that $f'''\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)>0$, $f'''\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)<0$ and $f'''(1)>0$. This means $f'''(x)$ has a root $t_1$ in $\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and another root $t_2$ in $\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$. These are the only roots of this polynomial.

With this we can draw the sign scheme of $f'''(x)$. It follows that $f''(x)$ is increasing when $x>1$ and decreasing when $x<0$.

**Roots of the second derivative:**

We see that $f''(1)<0$ and $f''\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)>0$ implying a root in $\left(1,\frac{3}{2}\right)$. This is the only root for $x>1$ since the function is increasing in this interval. We also see that $f''(0)<0$ while $f''\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)>0$ so that a root of $f''(x)$ lies in $\left(-\frac{1}{2},0\right)$. This is the only root for $x<0$ since the function is monotonically decreasing in this interval.

Now we can use Descartes' rule of signs which tells us that $f''(x)$ has either $1$ or $3$ positive roots. If there are $3$ roots, the $2$ other positive roots (or $1$ root of multiplicity $2$) can only occur in $(0,1)$. We will show in the next part that the roots of $f'(x)$ do not even occur in $(0,1)$, and hence they are irrelevant for us, both in finding the roots of $f'(x)$ and also in finding the sign of $f''(x)$ over the roots of $f'(x)$.

So $f''(x)$ has two roots each of which lie in $\left(1,\frac{3}{2}\right)$ and $\left(-\frac{1}{2},0\right)$. Both of these are single roots, since both of them are not roots of $f'''(x)$. It follows that $f'(x)$ increases when $x>1.5$ or $x<-0.5$. Two roots may also lie in $(0,1)$, but not necessarily.

**Roots of the first derivative**:

Notice $f'\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)<0$ while $f'(2)>0$ which means there is a root $r_1$ in $\left(\frac{3}{2},2\right)$ and also that there is no other root for $x>\frac{3}{2}$. Also, $f'(-1)<0$ and $f'\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)>0$ indicating there is a root $r_2$ in $\left(-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right)$. This is the only negative root of $f'(x)$. The third root is $0$.

Now notice $f'(x)=0$ means $x(3x^2-3x-2\sqrt{3})\underbrace{(3x^2-3x+2\sqrt{3})}_{discriminant \ \Delta}=0$. We notice $\Delta <0$, so there are only three roots for the second derivative.

It is easy to check that $f''(r_1)>0$ and $f''(r_2)>0$. So there are two minimizers for $f(x)$ which are $r_1 \in \left(\frac{3}{2},2\right)$ and $r_2\in \left(-1,\frac{-1}{2}\right)$.

NOTE: I doubt such a question was asked in JEE mains mathematics. Time is of the essence in the exam whilst this solution is very long-winded, unless if the the MCQ options of the question provided some reasonable hints to simplify solving the question. Regardless, I am fairly certain that this solution is doable given enough time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter version of the answer by
**mathlove**:

Note that
$$
f'(x) = 20x(3x^2(x-1)^2-4) = 20x(3/16(4u^2-1)^2-4)
$$
where $u = x + 1/2$. The auxiliary function $$
g(u) = 3/16(4u^2-1)^2-4
$$
is even and has a local maximum at $u = 0$, with $g(0) < 0$. There must therefore be two local minima. These are clearly at  $\pm 1/2$, and $g(\pm 1/2) = -4 < 0$. Therefore $g$ has exactly two zeros $-u_0 <  -1/2 < 1/2 < u_0$, and $g$ is locally decreasing at $-u_0$ and locally increasing at $+u_0$.

This means that $f'(x) = 20xg(x+1/2)$ has exactly three zeroes, namely at $0, -u_0-1/2, u_0 - 1/2$. Recall that $-u_0 - 1/2 < 0 < u_0 - 1/2$.

$f'$ changes sign from negative to positive  at $-u_0 - 1/2$, so this is a local minimum of $f$.

$f'$ change sign from positive to negative at $x = 0$, so this is a local maximum of $f$.

$f'$ changes sign from negative to positive  at $u_0 - 1/2$, so this is a local minimum of $f$.

Therefore $f$ has exactly two local minima.